# Load an image from its absolute path in Matlab also if is not included in working directory

Tags: matlab

I have the absolute path of an image `myabspath`

```
D:\myimages\venus\surface\im0012.jpg
```

I have tried

```
im=imread(myabspath);
```

but doesn't work because seems that `imread` accept only the name of a file in the current working directory.

I have also tried

```
f=load(myabspath);
```

But get an error "*Argument must contain a string*".

Seems a pretty basilar operation but unfortunately I haven't found the solution.

**EDIT**
Seems that the problem is caused by the fact `myabspath`is not a regular String but a `cell`, I have tried to use 
`myabspath=cellstr(myabspath)` 
but I continue to receive the error that tell me that `myabspath` is not a string, but if I call

```
display(myabspath)
```

I see the right path. Any solution?

Comment: That is not true.  For `imread`, you can specify a **full path** to where you want to load your images.  Where did you determine the fact that `imread` only accepts a name from the current working directory?  Also, please show your **entire code** to reproduce your problem.  If your path is a string like at the beginning of your code, `imread` should work.

Comment: Is your path variable definitely a string, not something odd like a string stored in a cell array?

Comment: you are right is stored as cell not a standard string... any solution to convert in normal String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `cell` that contains the *String path*, you don't need any conversion, is enough access the content of the cell using `{index}`.

Eg 
if you have to get the first element use `myabspath{1}`

`imread` is able to read images from absolute paths

Answer (score 2):

It seems strange.

Did you get a specific error message?

Does the image actually exists?

Did you, perhaps, write a "your own" `imread` function which overrides the "MatLab" one?

According to MatLab (R2012b) help, `imread` also accepts "full pathname"

> imread Read image from graphics file.
>       A = imread(FILENAME,FMT) reads a grayscale or color image from the file
>       specified by the string FILENAME. **If the file is not in the current
>       directory, or in a directory on the MATLAB path, specify the full 
>       pathname**.

I've replicated your folder structure, I did not add it to the MatLab path, nevertheless and I've been able to read an image with `imread` by specifying the full pathname.

This is the output I've got:

```
>> myabspath='D:\myimages\venus\surface\im0012.jpg'

myabspath =

D:\myimages\venus\surface\im0012.jpg

>> im=imread(myabspath);
>> whos
  Name             Size                Bytes  Class    Attributes

  im             421x500x3            631500  uint8              
  myabspath        1x36                   72  char
```

Comment: No I haven't any imread function definde and call the imread of Matlab... the error is `must be a String`

Comment: iI use display(myabspath) I'm able to see the right path but Seems that the problem is caused by the fact is stored as cell not as standard String... any suggestion to get the string before call imread?